Getting error in angular 8 project regarding ivy
I have a project which was working fine and now it is throwing error all thought the project and this is from app module.
Can you also explain what needs to be added in declaration and import
'ChartsModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
charts.d.ts(33, 40): This likely means that the library (ng2-charts) which declares ChartsModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
I am expecting error free code

just confirm if you are using ng2-chart@1 which is compatible v2-v9

"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0", This is the version being used
